# Improve php fragment

Tags: php, optimization

I have a PHP fragment that have to be something like this:

```
$a = false;
if($something) $a = true;
elseif($xyz < 45) $a = true;
elseif($response % 5 == 0) $a = true;
elseif($etc >14) $a = true;
```

Then I was wondering if there is a way to write better this, like in RoR, that could be something like:

```
$a = true if($something or ($xyz < 45) or ($response % 5 == 0) or ($etc >14));
```

The goal is not to repeat the "*$a = true*" so many times...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using `elseif`, you can write it in one line like this:

```
$a = $something || $xyz < 45 || $response % 5 == 0 || $etc >14;
```